# Package configuration for sqlite3 is not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rubygems

I'm trying to run rails server and there is problem with sqlite3.

When i run `bin/rails server`

> Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (~> 1.4)' in locally installed gems.

> Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

So i try to run `bundle install`

> Installing sqlite3 1.4.2 with native extensions

> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

And the last thing I tried is checking the log file in /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/sqlite3-1.4.2/mkmf.log

> package configuration for sqlite3 is not found find_header: checking
> for sqlite3.h... -------------------- no
>
> "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -o conftest
> -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.7.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.7.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/ruby2.7-aN7IdK/ruby2.7-2.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-z,relro
> -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.7  -lm   -lc"
>
> checked program was:
>
> ```
> /* begin */
> 1: #include "ruby.h"
> 2: 
> 3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
> 4: {
> 5:   return !!argv[argc];
> 6: }
> /* end */
> ```
>
> "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -E -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-2.7.0
> -I/usr/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.7.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/ruby2.7-aN7IdK/ruby2.7-2.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC  conftest.c -o conftest.i" conftest.c:3:10: fatal error: sqlite3.h: No
> such file or directory
>
> ```
> 3 | #include <sqlite3.h>
>   |          ^~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated.
> ```
>
> checked program was:
>
> ```
> /* begin */
> 1: #include "ruby.h"
> 2: 
> 3: #include <sqlite3.h>
> /* end */
> ```
>
> ---

Any suggestion?

Comment: do you have sqlite3 installed locally if not then install it if yes then in your Gemfile replace `gem 'sqlite3'` line by `gem ‘sqlite3’, git: “https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: “add-gemspec”` and then try bundle install again

Comment: I tried your method sir, but it gives me another error.
[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: Undefined local variable or method `“add' for Gemfile. Bundler cannot continue.
 #  from /home/chip/rbonrails/blog/Gemfile:9
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
 >  gem 'sqlite3', "git: “https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: “add-gemspec”
 #  # Use Puma as the app server
>  #  -------------------------------------------

Comment: change branch name to `1-3-stable` and or remove then try

Comment: An alternative is really just to skip sqlite completely and use Postgres, MySQL or whatver other database you're actually going to use for the project. The only point of sqlite is that its easy to setup if you want to fiddle around. If the setup is giving you trouble then its a waste of time.

Comment: I'll try that, thx for the advice